# Chain list of calls on an object, then return the modified object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails object, namely `Order`. I also have a list of calls I need to call on this object: `[:address, :number]`. I would like to chain all these methods on the given object, and return the result. So, the end value for the above would be equal to a call to: `obj.address.number`.

Currently, I've done this using:

```
 obj = Order.first
 [:address, :name].each { |m| obj = obj.send(m) }
 puts obj
```

But I feel there certainly is a best way of achieving this using a more "ruby" approach.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. What's wrong with just calling `obj.address.number`?

Comment: Because the list of calls is dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Ruby#inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to achieve it

```
result_object = [:address, :name].inject(Order.first, :send)
puts result_object
```

It is analogous to

```
Order.first.address.name
```